# how to use xlsx and xsd file in drools 6.3.0 kie workbench

Tags: xsd, drools, drools-guvnor, kie, kie-workbench

I have a xlsx file,
[image]

I have created a xlsx file using New Item-> Decision Table(Spread Sheet) option. I have uploaded the file, but after getting a successfully uploaded msg it redirects me to upload page
[image]

I am not getting how to use this xlsx file  for creating decision table. Also the same is happening with me for xsd file also. I am a newbie to Drools 6.3.0. can anyone please suggest me how to use these file in Drools kie Workbench.

I am not getting the convert option, after uploading xlsx file. I have successfully build the project.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If correctly formatted, XLSX file is already a decision table. You'd create it in the LibreOffice or similar tool. If you upload it to the workbench, the rules will be activated during the execution. It is also possible to design the decision table in LibreOffice, then upload it to the workbench and convert it to the "Guided Decision Table" - which will allow you to make further changes to this decision table directly in the workbench.
See this screenshot:
[image: convert XLSX table]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, As per your screenshot you are getting Convert option once uploaded the file. But I am not getting convert option. Do you have any idea why is it happening so.?

Comment: Can you please share a sample xls/xlsx file for reference

Comment: And do you have any idea how we can use xsd file or how can we import any external files in our project.. Thanks in advance